# handlebars should i create all my pages with handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

noob question, i start create handlebars templates and is kind useful.

I can create templates without load a html tag in html file, so should I just use handlebars and stop use html tags in my html? what you recommend guys? its a good practice or no?  thank you.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang=""> <!--<![endif]-->
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
            <title></title>
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
           <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/stylesheets/style.css"> -->
            <style>
                body {
                    padding-top: 50px;
                    padding-bottom: 20px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body class="body">
            <!--[if lt IE 8]>
                <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
            <![endif]-->


    <script src="public/javascripts/libs/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="public/javascripts/libs/handlebars-v3.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="public/javascripts/index-template.js"></script> 
    <script src="public/javascripts/templates/h1-h2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```